# Show theorem definition in Coq

Tags: coq

I'd like to view the definition of a Standard Library theorem which I found through `Search`. I think seeing the definition will help me complete a similar theorem.

Doing `Print Rdiv_lt_0_compat.` yields:

```
Rdiv_lt_0_compat = 
fun (a b : R) (H : (0 < a)%R) (H0 : (0 < b)%R) =>
Rmult_lt_0_compat a (/ b) H (Rinv_0_lt_compat b H0)
     : forall a b : R, (0 < a)%R -> (0 < b)%R -> (0 < a / b)%R

Argument scopes are [R_scope R_scope _ _]
```

Setting `Set Printing All.` doesn't help. There's nothing extra available in [the docs page.](https://coq.inria.fr/library/Coq.Reals.RIneq.html#Rdiv_lt_0_compat)

Comment: "The quotient of two positive numbers is positive because division is multiplication by the reciprocal (invisible, maybe try `Locate "/".` to find the definition) and the reciprocal of a positive number is positive (`Rinv_0_lt_compat`) and the product of positive numbers is positive (`Rmult_lt_0_compat`)." The proof is given in Gallina, which is not always readable by human eyes. The Gallina proof is the output of an Ltac program, which you can only(?) find in the [source code](https://github.com/coq/coq/blob/34e62d05df4ecd833f87115aa0e986ef7626359e/theories/Reals/RIneq.v#L2128-L2131).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The whole Coq system is based on the idea *Proofs are programs, logical formulas are types*.  When you consider a theorem, it is a proof (a program) and its statement is a logical formula (the type of a program).   In the very
first years of Coq, there was no tactic language, every proof was defined using the same keywords as when defining a program.

After a few years, it was recognized that writing the programs entirely by hand was long and tiresome, so a *tactic* language was invented to explain how to construct the *proof-programs* in a shorter and less difficult way.  But what is recorded and eventually checked are still the programs that you see using `Print`.

When building a proof-program, the tactic `intros` constructs anonymous function expressions (also known as lambdas, usually written with the keyword `fun`, and `apply` constructs an application of a function to a certain number arguments, which `apply` infers or leaves to the user as goals.  The tactics `induction` and `rewrite` are similar, but they apply theorems that are not
given by the user.  The tactic `destruct` essentially produces a piece of programs that is a pattern-matching construct.

With `Rdiv_lt_0_compat`, you are lucky that the proof built by the tactic is quite short.  Often, proofs written using tactics produce programs that are much longer.

If instead of the program, you want to see the sequence of tactics that generated it, you need to find it in the sources of the system, because this
is not kept in the memory of the proof assistant.  Here are the clues.

```
Require Import Reals.

Locate Rdiv_lt_0_compat.
```

the answer is `Constant Coq.Reals.RIneq.Rdiv_lt_0_compat`

This sequence of names indicates the hierarchy of modules in which the theorem is kept.  The first name `Coq` expresses that this theorem is in the Coq sources, essentially in directory `...theories/`, the second name `Reals`, indicates that you should look in tge sub directory `...theories/Reals`.
The fourth name should not be used as a directory name, but as file name.  So you should look in the file `RIneq.v`

So go an look in https://github.com/coq/coq/tree/v8.12/theories/Reals/RIneq.v and you will probably find the script fragment that was used to generate your theorem (for the 8.12 version of Coq).  I just checked, the theorem appears at line https://github.com/coq/coq/blob/c95bd4cf015a3084a8bddf6d3640458c9c25b455/theories/Reals/RIneq.v#L2106

The sequence of names provided by `Locate` is not a sure way to find the file where the script for a theorem is stored.  The correspondence between the long name and the file path is broken when the theorem is defined using modules and functor instantiation.  In that case, you have to rely on stronger knowledge of how the Coq system works.

Comment: Also just FYI, some IDEs may provide some features to directly "jump to definition" (internally relying on commands like [`Locate`](https://coq.github.io/doc/V8.12+beta1/refman/proof-engine/vernacular-commands.html#coq:cmd.locate) indeed). See e.g. https://github.com/cpitclaudel/company-coq/blob/master/img/jump-to-definition.gif

Comment: wow thanks. This is the level of detail I needed. I've been reading & viewing a lot about Coq lately but hadn't heard the bit in your intro about the development of the tactic language. I was taking it at face value and didn't understand what that mess was when I did `Print` on a theorem.
It sounds like I need Vim/Emacs tags setup for a cloned repo of Coq to be decent at navigating... Appears to be what @ErikMD was suggesting. I've already felt I needed more than just basic `Search`

Comment: @user2183336 BTW regarding user interfaces for Coq, there is a dedicated web page at this URL: https://coq.inria.fr/user-interfaces.html